# grouping a dictionary by equal values

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Maybe a very common and easy question in here...
my purpose is that grouping a dictionary according to its values for example;

```
D = {"k1":1,"k2":2,"k3":1,"k4":0,"k5":1,"k6":0}
```

output look like

```
part1=[0,[k4,k6]] part2=[1,[k1,k3,k5]] part3=[2,[k2]]
```

Comment: What have you tried, and why hasn't it worked for you?

Answer (score 1):

```
def filter_by_value(dictionary, value):
    return [value, [i for i in dictionary if dictionary[i] == value]]
```

And if you want to do it with all the values the dictionary has you can just do:

```
def group_by_values(dictionary):
    #set ensures there are no repeated values
    return [filter_by_value(dictionary, i) for i in set(dictionary.values())]
```

Last but not least, if you want the list to be sorted just add a sorting function after the set:

```
def group_by_values(dictionary):
    #set ensures there are no repeated values
    return [filter_by_value(dictionary, i) for i in sorted(set(dictionary.values()))]
```

Comment: thank you so much Yadkee, one small step for you but one big step for me:)

Comment: I'm glad it helps you :)